# Uppercase en formula de fecha crystal report c#

Tags: crystal-reports

Tengo un pequeño detalle con una formula que contiene una fecha almacenada como varchar, realizo la conversion de la siguiente manera en la formula de crystal report sin inconvenientes

```
(cDate( {fn_find_Presupuesto_Impresion.PRE_ELA_PRE}))
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se ve en la imagen el resultado personalizado me arroja el mes en minúscula al tratar de hacer la conversión a mayúscula con la sgte formula arroja un mensaje en esta parte `"MMM"` que indica que se han pasado demasiado parámetros a esta función

```
UCase(MonthName(Month(cdate({fn_find_Presupuesto_Impresion.PRE_ELA_PRE},"MMM"))))
```

Como podría arreglar esta formula para que al final quede 06/MARZO/2023 , de antemano agradezco su ayuda

Comment: ¿Probaste con `UCase(CStr( {fn_find_Presupuesto_Impresion.PRE_ELA_PRE}, "dd/MM/yyyy" ))`? desde [How to convert the month into uppercase in Crystal Report?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46821988/how-to-convert-the-month-into-uppercase-in-crystal-report)

Comment: @HéctorM al probar esa función me arroja el mismo error que se han pasado demasiado parámetros a esta función, el tipo de datos es nvarchar(10)